# A question on connectedness of $S:=\{z:|z|<1\text{ or }|z-2|<1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $S$ be the open set defined by $S:=\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|<1\text{ or }|z-2|<1\}$. State why $S$ is not connected.

I have no idea how to solve.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

The region defined by $|z|<1$ is an open disk, centered at $0$, with radius $1$.

The region defined by $|z-2|<1$ is an open disk, centered at $2$, with radius $1$.

The two open disks have no points in common.

Thus, $S$ is the union of two nonempty disjoint open sets, so $S$ is not connected.

Answer (score 0):

because $\left | z-2 \right | < 1$ an $\left | z \right | < 1$ are  two  open ball and  they are disjoint so S  is  not  patch connected so it is not connected   ( because in  the plane open sets are  patch connected  iff  are connected,and S is  open  )